# Unity - Detect if OpenGL on Android doesnt support a certain operation

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, textures, gpu, texture2d

I'm using a Texture scaler code found on pastebin (code below) and for some reason it doesnt work on some devices, it produces an invalid texture. One device I'm certain it doesnt work is the Nexus 7 tablet (2012), but it probably doesnt work on many others. But on the vast majority of devices it does work.

I'm not sure why it doesnt work, or on what operation it fails, but given this scaler is done on GPU it's much faster than other versions of scalers I found.

What I want to do then is somehow detect it doesnt work so I can run the slower version of the scaling algorithm. Any ideas on either:

1) How to detect? I thought of checking if the texture is invalid after running, but it could behave differently on different devices (on the Nexus 7 it always turns the pixel colors to 205,205,205)

2) Why it doesnt work? I found on some searches that some GPU operations on Nexus 7 fails if the texture is NPOT, but I dont know if it is related to this. I also thought maybe it's related to Open GL ES version, but I dont know how to check the version (maybe Nexus 7 is GLES 2.0 and this scaler only works on GLES 3.0+?).

Thanks

```
using UnityEngine;

// from: https://pastebin.com/qkkhWs2J

/// A unility class with functions to scale Texture2D Data.
///
/// Scale is performed on the GPU using RTT, so it's blazing fast.
/// Setting up and Getting back the texture data is the bottleneck.
/// But Scaling itself costs only 1 draw call and 1 RTT State setup!
/// WARNING: This script override the RTT Setup! (It sets a RTT!)        
///
/// Note: This scaler does NOT support aspect ratio based scaling. You will have to do it yourself!
/// It supports Alpha, but you will have to divide by alpha in your shaders,
/// because of premultiplied alpha effect. Or you should use blend modes.
public class TextureScaler
{

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns a scaled copy of given texture.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tex">Source texure to scale</param>
    /// <param name="width">Destination texture width</param>
    /// <param name="height">Destination texture height</param>
    /// <param name="mode">Filtering mode</param>
    public static Texture2D scaled(Texture2D src, int width, int height, FilterMode mode = FilterMode.Trilinear)
    {
            Rect texR = new Rect(0,0,width,height);
            _gpu_scale(src,width,height,mode);

            //Get rendered data back to a new texture
            Texture2D result = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, true);
            result.Resize(width, height);
            result.ReadPixels(texR,0,0,true);
            return result;                 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Scales the texture data of the given texture.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tex">Texure to scale</param>
    /// <param name="width">New width</param>
    /// <param name="height">New height</param>
    /// <param name="mode">Filtering mode</param>
    public static void scale(Texture2D tex, int width, int height, FilterMode mode = FilterMode.Trilinear)
    {
            Rect texR = new Rect(0,0,width,height);
            _gpu_scale(tex,width,height,mode);

            // Update new texture
            tex.Resize(width, height);
            tex.ReadPixels(texR,0,0,true);
            tex.Apply(true);        //Remove this if you hate us applying textures for you :)
    }

    // Internal unility that renders the source texture into the RTT - the scaling method itself.
    static void _gpu_scale(Texture2D src, int width, int height, FilterMode fmode)
    {
            //We need the source texture in VRAM because we render with it
            src.filterMode = fmode;
            src.Apply(true);       

            //Using RTT for best quality and performance. Thanks, Unity 5
            RenderTexture rtt = new RenderTexture(width, height, 32);

            //Set the RTT in order to render to it
            Graphics.SetRenderTarget(rtt);

            //Setup 2D matrix in range 0..1, so nobody needs to care about sized
            GL.LoadPixelMatrix(0,1,1,0);

            //Then clear & draw the texture to fill the entire RTT.
            GL.Clear(true,true,new Color(0,0,0,0));
            Graphics.DrawTexture(new Rect(0,0,1,1),src);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code and note proper attribution. While I can search and find what I believe is the same code, no one knows for sure.

Comment: You have to show the code or API that's not working on some devices  like Morrison said.

Comment: Sorry, edited and added the code. I thought initially it would be too much code to paste that's why I didnt paste (and SO wouldnt allow me to put the pastebin link alone)